# Explain Query Logic - Get First Wednesday of Current Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT      
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()),
GETDATE())), 0),'First Monday of Current Month'
```

This query returns the first Monday of the current month. I just want to know how this query is working and how do I get the first Wednesday of the current month instead.

Comment: What do you exactly need to know?

Comment: I'm not sure if "SELECT DATEADD" will return anything, DATEADD already returns a value. Where did you find this query?

Comment: This query returns first Monday of current month. I just want to know how this query is working and how do i get first Wednesday of current month

Comment: Just change the last 0 to a '2'.

Comment: Learn to read documentation and to debug!!!!  Have you even tried to understand what each of the function does???  Have you tried to run it piece by piece???  If you just look at it, it will not say anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to know how this query is working

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '1900-01-01')   --'Monday'
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, 0)   --also 'Monday'
```

January 1, 1900 was a Monday. When you add a week to a Monday you get another Monday. If you add 6,170 weeks to a Monday- you still get a Monday.  As of 04/10/2018 there have been 6,170 weeks since Jan 1, 1900.

Simply, the query calculates these weeks, adding 6,170 weeks since Monday, Jan 1 1900.

> how do I get the first Wednesday of the current month instead?

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '1900-01-03')   --Wednesday
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, 2)   --also Wednesday
```

January 3, 1900 is represented by integer 2.  We changed a 0 (which was monday) to a 2 (wednesday).  If you add 6,170 weeks to a Wednesday you still get a Wednesday.

In the query there is a 0.  We can change this to a 2:

```
SELECT      
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()),
GETDATE())), 2),'First Wednesday of Current Month'
```

Edit: I can make this perhaps a little clearer by getting rid of the integer and putting in the actual date:

```
SELECT      
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()),
GETDATE())), '1900-01-03'),'First Wednesday of Current Month'
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify the whole:

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())), 0)
```

you can think at it in this way:

```
-- number of day to go back to reach 1st week of month
z = 6 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) 

-- a day in 1st week of the month 
y = DATEADD(DAY, z, GETDATE()) 

-- number of weeks between 0 (1900-01-01) and 1st week of month
x = DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, y) 

-- add the number of weeks elapsed to 1900-01-01 to get the datetime of 1st day of 1st week of month
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, x, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the first Wednesday of the month, as requested in your comment:

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())), 2) 
AS 'First Wednesday of Current Month'
```

I changed your last 0 in the DATEADD function to a 2, as this is a zero based representation of the days of the week, 0 being Monday.

You can use the "Try it yourself" functionality on W3schools to play around with queries and figure them out: [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp). Just paste your query in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many formula to get first Wednesday of the current month including above scripts but they were not working right if the month starts with Wednesday. (2022-06-01 can be tried). So I succeed it with my own way, you can see the sql below.

```
     select
     FirstWednesdayofCurrentMonth = 
     case when datepart(dw,EOMONTH(dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))) = 3 
          then dateadd(dd,1,EOMONTH(dateadd(month,-1,getdate())))       -- if month start with wednesday
     else convert(date, DATEADD(DAY,(DATEDIFF(DAY,2,DATEADD(d,1,EOMONTH(dateadd(month,-1,getdate())))) / 7) * 7 + 7, 2))    -- if not 
     end
```